# Alert popup when variables becomes TRUE

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I use ajax to recive some variables from a php script. I want to run a JavaScript alert-function window if a variable becomes TRUE. When the user confirms the alert, I want to send a new value back to another php who updates a table in sqlite and the alarm function returns to normal.

My problem is that i use a setInterval to update the variables every second. This means that my alert-window also pop up once a second..

Is there any nicer way to do this?

Her is some of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

setInterval(function(){

$.getJSON('statusdata.php',function(data) {

hops = data["add_hops"];

if (hops == 1)
{
add_hops();
}

});
}, 1000);
```

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function add_hops()
{
startwindow=window.open("http://192.168.1.5/Birger/hops_alarm.html", "startwindow",         
"location=1,                          
status=0,scrollbars=0,width=750px,hight=350px");
startwindow.moveTo(640,300);
}   

</script>
```

Comment: Have you considered using websockets instead of ajax?

Comment: You can try a popup window insted of alert box

Comment: I have tried to use popup window, but since the variabel I use is local in the function it runs the popup window once a secound. I think i can solve it if i can get the variabel global.?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript do not grantee `setInterval` itself to work properly. Let alone ajax. ajax is async nature. Use callback on ajax `success` to determine whether pop-up show or not.

When you make too much ajax request the browser queue them. So they do not guarantee to end's in 1 second.

**Edit**
From the comment:

using call on your ajax call assure you that your add_hops function won't be called before your ajax call terminate.

Thanks you.

Comment: +1, using call on your ajax call assure you that your add_hops function won't be called before your ajax call terminate

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prevent your code from duplicating the alerts is to capture the timeout to a variable like so:

```
var myTimeout = setTimeout(function () {

    // …

}, 1000);
```

Now you have a reference to the timeout, you can cancel it with this line:

```
if (myTimeout) clearTimeout(myTimeout);
```

To make this work in your function, you need to insert that clearTimeout line into your anonymous function like this:

```
var hops = null;
var myTimeout = setInterval(function(){

    if (hops == 1) {
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);
        return;
    }
    $.getJSON('statusdata.php',function(data) {
        hops = data["add_hops"];
        if (hops == 1) {
            add_hops();
        }
    });

}, 1000);
```

Adding the clearTimeout() call to the anonymous function rather than the $.getJSON() call prevents the code from potentially executing an un-necessary AJAX request on laggy connections.

> References
>
> - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp